# Angular Distance Question

Tags: geometry

I am having difficulty determining the angular distance associated with an object that is $355$ ft wide and $250$ miles away from any point of reference.

The online calculators that I have tried show me anywhere between $15$ and $35$ degrees.

Thank you in advance for any help the you can provide!

Comment: What part is giving you difficulty?

Comment: Thank you for reaching out John Doe.. in all honesty.. I am not sure of the formula and such. Based on the calculators I have used I see that I need to get both measurements into the same measurement type.

Comment: Yes, you need to convert the miles to feet before you can start this problem.

Comment: So 355 feet and converting 250 miles into 1,320,000 feet. I am not understanding the triangle and pulling the angle out of the 3 points. TY!

Comment: You probably want to draw a picture first with a point on one end and a short segment far away from that point (representing the 355 ft object). Then, you can create two right triangles by drawing a line from the point to the middle of the segment. This will allow you to use Pythagorean theorem to solve for the distance from the point to either side of the segment. Finally, you can use law of cosines to solve for the angle you are looking for.

Comment: I see.. so the 2 angles on either side of the object would be at around 90 as well.. makjng the point of origin angle as 0.0155 degrees

Comment: That sounds like it could be right. I haven’t done any calculations.